# React redux reducer - change value from a string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm trying to change ma state value dynamically with this code but it doesn't work what am I doing wrong here.

```
const defaultState = {
team_a_player_1_points: 0,
team_a_player_2_points: 0,
team_a_player_3_points: 0,
team_a_player_4_points: 0,
team_a_player_5_points: 0,
team_b_player_1_points: 0,
team_b_player_2_points: 0,
team_b_player_3_points: 0,
team_b_player_4_points: 0,
team_b_player_5_points: 0
};

function homepageReducer (state = defaultState , action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_POINT':
     const scoring_player = `team_${action.player_team}_player_${action.player_number}_points`;
      return {...state, scoring_player: state.scoring_player + 1};
    case 'REMOVE_POINT':
      return {...state, };        
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats not working do you get any errors? by the way are you sure your state has a property of `scoring_player`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to update a key in your state that does not exist.
you can use dynamically calculated object keys in es6

Try this one

```
function homepageReducer (state = defaultState , action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_POINT':
     const scoring_player = `team_${action.player_team}_player_${action.player_number}_points`;
      return {...state, [scoring_player]: state[scoring_player] + 1};
    case 'REMOVE_POINT':
      return {...state, };        
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

note that `[scoring_player]` will be unpacked in the string value that you calculate right above the state calculation.

So if you you calculate `scoring_player` to be `team_a_player_1_points` for example the next line is evaluated as this:

```
return {...state, team_a_player_1_points: state['team_a_player_1_points'] + 1};
```